# Thread creation using a function of an object in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm a beginner, and I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2015. I always see thread creation like this:

```
thread nameThread(functionName);
```

The doubt is: how to create thread that use a function member of a object, and this function needs a pointer to an attribute of another object ? Something like this:

```
if(something == true){
  thread nameThread( object.function( &anotherObject.attribute ) );
}
.
.
.
nameThread.join();
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the olden days we had to use black magic to do this. But `std::thread` is clever enough to provide overloads for us that achieve it "automatically":

```
std::thread nameThread(
   &theTypeOfObject::function,  // function to invoke
   &object,                     // first arg (implicit "this" pointer)
   &anotherObject.attribute     // second arg (first one you see)
);
```

Comment: `&theTypeOfObject::function`; pretty sure the ampersand is required.

Comment: @AlanStokes: True. It's the object pointer that doesn't need it, come to think of it, as a reference is acceptable there too (though I prefer passing a pointer in this case).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I did what you told me. But I have this: 
Error (active)  a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object labirinto

Comment: Error C2660 'explorador::explorar': function does not take 0 arguments            (explorador::explorar is theTypeOfObject::function )

Comment: @smallCock: You made a mistake. You forgot to provide the arguments.

Comment: if I put the arguments, like this: &theTypeOfObject::function(& anotherObject.attribute )     I have this error: Error C2352 'explorador::explorar': illegal call of non-static member function

Comment: @smallCock: Why do you do it like that? That is not what I instructed you to do.

Comment: I did that because when I put your instruction :  &theTypeOfObject::function,  // function to invoke  I had this error message : Error C2660 'theTypeOfObject::function': function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: @smallCock: You must have written it wrong. [It works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/241acfe982db6b7c).

Comment: Yes, maybe. I will see what I can do here, but, thank you anyway :) !!